# Flutter : how to ignore rule of lines_longer_than_80_chars

Tags: android-studio, flutter

**How to ignore rule of "lines_longer_than_80_chars"**

I use  `pedantic: ^1.8.0` lib for add Lints.

I dont which linter rules add for this. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Add the below lines in `analysis_options.yaml` file

```yaml
analyzer:
  errors:
    lines_longer_than_80_chars: ignore
```

Comment: Can I apply `lines_longer_than_80_chars: ignore` for a single file and still apply the `lines_longer_than_80_chars` for all other files? I Tried adding "// ignore_for_file: lines_longer_than_80_chars" but, it did not work. Flutter version 3.7.7

Answer (score 2):

Modify the `analysis_options.yaml` and add the `lines_longer_than_80_chars: ignore`

My `analysis_options.yaml` looks like this:

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml
linter:
  rules:
    lines_longer_than_80_chars: ignore
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating `analysis_options.yaml` didn't help in my case as running `dart format .` was still formatting my files even when **lines_longer_than_80_chars** was disabled. What helped was running format command with parameter forcing custom line length. Source [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37657#issuecomment-517204671)

```
dart format --line-length 120 .
```